# Wave dashboard to get detail rows from grouped result

Tags: dashboard, einstein-analytics

I am using a group by SAQL (i.e. pivot table) to get records that are not unique for given 3 field combination.
ex. Output is fields a, b ,c, count(rows) if count(rows) > 1 (Group By a,b,c)

Issue is I need to display some additional fields in this result, bu since I cannot group by those fields I am not able select them.

Is there a way I can use result from this SAQL/pivot table (say all values returned for field a) to fetch another table with additioanl fields to display.

Answer (score 0):

Use first (FIELD NAME ) or last(FIELD NAME) in the foreach statement.